# chai-smoothie: to.eventually.be.displayed on a function doesn't work?

Tags: serenity-js

First-off, thanks for the chai-smoothie!

I've been trying to polish some of the test code and use chai-smoothie more, but I have ran into some trouble:

This is what it looked like before:

```
return expect(Promise.all([
    userMenuPage.userMenuItemIcon.isDisplayed(),
    userMenuPage.userMenuItemText().isDisplayed()
])).to.eventually.be.eql([true, true])
```

and this is how I expected it to work in chai smoothie

```
expect(userMenuPage.userMenuItemIcon).to.eventually.be.displayed
expect(userMenuPage.userMenuItemText()).to.eventually.be.displayed
```

when running the new code, I receive the following error:

```
   Step Definition: steps/userMenuSteps.js:23
   Message:
     TypeError: assertion._obj.locator is not a function
         at <repo>/tests/node_modules/chai-smoothie/lib/src/chai-smoothie.ts:42:65
         at <repo>/tests/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:798:32
         at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (<repo>/tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
         at TaskQueue.execute_ (<repo>/tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
         at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (<repo>/tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
         at asyncRun (<repo>/tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27)
         at <repo>/tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Page model definition looks like this:

```
userMenuItemText: () => $('#desktop-menu #desktop-menu-classic span').getText(),
userMenuItemIcon: $('#desktop-menu #desktop-menu-classic .fa-fjunk'),
```

The issue is with the second row "userMenuPage.userMenuItemText().isDisplayed()". If I just use "userMenuPage.userMenuItemIcon.isDisplayed()", then I get no problem, and if I just use "userMenuPage.userMenuItemText().isDisplayed()", then I get the failure.

Do you have any recommendationts on how to overcome this and still use chai smoothie?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the assertion `to.eventually.be.displayed` applied to the text of the element, rather than the element itself.

**Update: as of version 0.2.1, chai-smoothie can work with either.**

Hope this helps!

Jan

---

Nevertheless, it might be cleaner to assert on the element to verify its visibility, and on its text to verify the contents:

So instead of:

```
const userMenuPage = {
    userMenuItemText: () => $('#desktop-menu #desktop-menu-classic span').getText(),
    userMenuItemIcon: $('#desktop-menu #desktop-menu-classic .fa-fjunk')
}
```

maybe try:

```
const userMenuPage = {
    userMenuItem: $('#desktop-menu #desktop-menu-classic span'),
    userMenuItemIcon: $('#desktop-menu #desktop-menu-classic .fa-fjunk')
}
```

and then:

```
expect(userMenuPage.userMenuItem).to.eventually.be.displayed
expect(userMenuPage.userMenuItem.getText()).to.eventually.equal('expected text')
```

---

With [Serenity/JS](http://serenity-js.org) you could also define the page object as follows:

```
class UserMenuPage {
    static Item      = Target.the('Menu item').located(by.css('#desktop-menu #desktop-menu-classic span');
    static Item_Text = Text.of(UserMenuPage.Item);

    static Item_Icon = Target.the('Menu icon').located(by.css('#desktop-menu #desktop-menu-classic .fa-fjunk');
}
```

which allows you to define "questions" such as `UserMenuPage.Item_Text` in the same place as `targets` and avoid having to call `.getText()` in the scenario.